What makes a statistic valid for monte carlo simulation?
A while back I was reading Garland et. al. (1993) about studying whether two groups of animals, say herbivores and carnivores differ in their mean value for some trait, like the amount of territory they travel across to find food.  The approach taken by Garland et. al. 1993 is to do a monte carlo simulation ANOVA where we simulate the the evolution of the two traits according to our null model and then calculate for each resulting dataset the ANOVA F-statistic to get the proper null distribution of our F-statistic so that we can see if the F-statistic for our real dataset is in the top 5% and therefore significant.
This is all good, but originally I was thinking a satisfactory approach would be to simply measure the mean difference between the two groups for each simulation and create a distribution of those differences or perhaps their absolute value.  Then, if the real data had a difference within the top 5%, I'd know the groups were significantly different.
I now understand that specific approach would not work for that specific problem because it does not account for the variance in the two groups which would mean some groups that have a top 5% difference are not actually significant because their abnormally high variance means the difference between groups is not actually dramatic enough to justify calling the two groups significantly different.  But in general, how do I know whether a statistic I develop to test something is correct?  What rules must be followed?
For example, in my current problem I have two different evolution models that could be responsible for the data.  My idea is to simulate a bunch of datasets according to the two competing models and then for each hypothesis set, create a histogram by binning similar values and then matching the observed dataset to the proper bin in each histogram and using the relative heights of the two bins the real dataset matches with to judge the relative likelihood of one model or the other generating the data.
For example, imagine I have two animals and two measurements per animal, percent of diet that is protein (0-100%), and length of territory (0-100 kilometers) and my first model assumes the 4 observations are from a multivariate normal with zero correlation, mean 0, and standard deviation 1, and my second model assumes the vector of 4 observations are drawn from a multivariate normal distribution with zero correlation, mean zero, and a standard deviation of sqrt(2).  Then in this case I would draw 10,000 samples from each of the two distributions and then bin them by counting for example,how many of the simulated results have their first-dimensional value between 0 and 0.1, their second-dimensional value
also in that range, etc.  Then if my real dataset is (0.01,0.09,0.08,0.08) I can see that perhaps there are 10 samples in the relevant bin from the first hypothesis, and only two in the same bin under the second hypothesis and therefore conclude the first hypothesis better explains the data.  But of course, I have no idea if this is a valid approach because I do not understand the rules about what types of things are allowed to be measured and tested with monte carlo.
I appreciate the help. thank you.
